# Problem accessing docker images by name after update docker from 19.03.11 to 20.10.9

Tags: docker

after updating docker on ol linux from version 19.03.11 to 20.10.9 I have problems working with the docker images by name. It only works with the docker ids.

```
[root]$ docker image ls | grep ftp
test__sftp                                                           V1         14b5dfc98968   2 years ago     206MB
test__sftp                                                           latest     14b5dfc98968   2 years ago     206MB
atmoz/sftp                                                           latest     6345f82053c6   3 years ago     190MB
[root]$ docker image tag test__sftp:latest test__sftp:latest2
Error response from daemon: No such image: test__sftp:latest
[root]$ docker image tag 14b5dfc98968 test__sftp:latest2
[root]$ docker image ls | grep ftp
test__sftp                                                           V1         14b5dfc98968   2 years ago     206MB
test__sftp                                                           latest     14b5dfc98968   2 years ago     206MB
test__sftp                                                           latest2    14b5dfc98968   2 years ago     206MB
atmoz/sftp                                                           latest     6345f82053c6   3 years ago     190MB
[root]$
```

Same with every image command as docker run, docker image rm aso.
It seems that the problem only occours by images that are implemented by docker load -i <file.tar> , not images from a gitlab container registry.
Hope you can help

Comment: If your `/var/lib/docker` tree is corrupted, the easy approach to stop Docker, delete it, and start over.  You will lose container-local filesystems (temporary anyways), images (can be rebuilt or re-pulled), and named volumes (potentially a real problem; restore from backups on a non-dev system).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in production environment it is sometimes not a good idea to delete f.e docker volumes which still contains user data. So we tried to delete only the overlay2/devicemapper directories in /var/lib/docker and /var/lib/docker/image/ and it seems that this works to solve the problem with the image tags and to keep the docker volumes. Nevertheless a new build/pull of the images must be done anyway.